# How can I use the old Courier bitmap font in a C# WinForms project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, regedit, bitmap-fonts

I'm attempting the exact same RegEdit clone project as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061763/reproduce-the-microsoft-registry-editor-edit-binary-value-window-in-vs-2010-c/13772949#13772949) and just like Darxis, I have been stumped by the "Edit Binary Value" dialog.

I believe the font used is the **original** Courier (**not** Courier New), but since this is an old-fashioned bitmap font, I can't use it in a modern C# WinForms project. I've tried every TTF version of Courier that I could find on the net, and none of them reproduce 0's in the same way as the original (i.e. four straight lines and **no curves**).

Call me anal but, like Darxis, I want the **exact same** look as Microsoft Registry Editor for my version. Then on top of the annoying backwards-incompatibility issues, every TTF font that I've installed just for this purpose has caused VS2012 to blurt out "Only TrueType fonts are supported. This is not a TrueType font", which is absolute BS!!

I've even tried creating an old GDI LOGFONT and using that (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273417/c-create-a-font-from-a-logical-font-logfont-quality-setting-is-ignored)) and that gives me the same dreaded error message about non-TrueType fonts. So is there **any** way to get old fonts (particularly coure.fon in C:\Windows\Fonts) to work with a C# project?! I am just about at my wits end over something so trivial and stupid, but I won't be able to rest until I figure it out!

Many thanks in advance to anyone who can help me solve this very annoying problem :-)